# How can I speed up Bootstrap Tooltips

Tags: php, javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have a table which dynamically reloads continually every 60 seconds. This keeps the data up to date.
I am using the script from here - http://www.michaelfretz.com/2010/04/21/using-ajax-to-load-data-from-php-into-your-website/

On the pages that have about 15 records, the Twitter Bootstrap tooltips work fine, they are speedy and look great.

On another page however I have over 400 records. Each record has a hover tooltip which shows the information from the database about that record. The information has already been outputted to the title tag but when hovering it takes more than a second before it appears which makes the whole page seem sluggish.

I'm thinking the reason for this is due to using the 'Rel' tag and twitter javascript which is live(Continually updating) , and therefore slows it down. But I'm not sure.

Is there any way to fix this..... or am I better to try and make a paginated table which loads the next page each time I click Next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 400 Records! Too much!

This is something seriously to do with the browser and system's performance. Displaying 400 records with `live()` is kinda crazy. The browser will crash for sure. Instead you can do one thing. Use `pagination` and display only a small sub set. Also, the users will find it difficult to navigate and search.

One another way is to use [datatables](https://datatables.net/). Load the full content in `table` and don't worry about anything. Datatables will take care of the rest. Pagination and Search are good features in this.

#### Screenshot of Datatables:

[image: Screenshot of Datatables]
<sub>(source: [webresourcesdepot.com](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/image/datatables.gif))</sub>

If you see this, everything from Searching, Sorting, giving tooltips are done in the client side, with minimal set of data. So the payload on the browser will be less and the users see the part, which they just require.

Answer (score 2):

400 records is a lot to expect someone to traverse within a 60 second period. Without actually seeing any actual html, it's a bit hard to make suggestions but here are three:

- Use the title attribute instead - see [about the Title attribute](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/a/aa101005.htm). This will mean that you are using inbuilt browser code rather than Bootstrap rendering for tooltips.
- Show a subject/content snippet for each row rather than just subject i.e. place the initial part of the content in available space after the actual subject. Most people have large monitors these days and with a responsive design you can show a lot of content after the subject.
- As you say, use pagination. Bootstrap provides one but it requires you to do the wiring.